# XML load file with PHP

Tags: php, xml

i am not sure what i am doing wrong but i just can't load XML with my PHP correctly.
I try it with load document and simplexml_load_file and so on but i am getting error all the time.

Example code i try:

```
$xnl_file = "xml.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xnl_file);
var_dump($xml);
```

Error i get:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): xml.xml:3: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\provisioning\index.php on line 3

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): <PartnershipList xmlns="http://www.audatex.com/SAXIF"> in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\provisioning\index.php on line 3

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\provisioning\index.php on line 3
bool(false)
```

XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CreationDateTime>Wed Nov 05 12:30:38 CET 2014</CreationDateTime>
<PartnershipList xmlns="http://www.audatex.com/SAXIF">
 <Partnership>
  <CountryOrganizationId>CZ</CountryOrganizationId>
  <PartnershipId>Contract_58AB4635-D9C6-A04E</PartnershipId>
  <OwnerId>MM-O-BDD15299</OwnerId>
  <PartnerIdList>
   <String>MM-O-2A10BCF</String>
  </PartnerIdList>
  <Contract>
   <CountryOrganizationId>CZ</CountryOrganizationId>
   <ContractId>Contract_58AB4635-D9C6-A04E</ContractId>
   <LaborRateList>
    <LaborRateDetail>
     <Role>Labor</Role>
     <Category>1</Category>
     <Rate Cur="CZK" Unit="h" MinValue="0" MaxValue="0">250.0</Rate>
    </LaborRateDetail>
    <LaborRateDetail>
     <Role>Paint</Role>
     <Category>2</Category>
     <Rate Cur="CZK" Unit="h" MinValue="0" MaxValue="0">350.0</Rate>
    </LaborRateDetail>
   </LaborRateList>
   <IdBlockCodeList>
    <IDBlockCode>
     <IDBlockCode>51</IDBlockCode>
     <Entry>100</Entry>
    </IDBlockCode>
   </IdBlockCodeList>
   <VehicleKind>Car</VehicleKind>
   <RepairKind>BodyRepair</RepairKind>
   <ManufacturerCode>07</ManufacturerCode>
   <Status>Active</Status>
   <CreatedBy>MM-P-69F997009BBFB4FC2C</CreatedBy>
   <CreationTimeStamp>2014-09-09T15:17:46.000</CreationTimeStamp>
   <UpdatedBy>MM-P-69F997009BBFB4FC2C</UpdatedBy>
   <UpdateTimeStamp>2014-10-15T10:49:18.000</UpdateTimeStamp>
   <FirstVersionContractId>Contract_58AB4635-D9C6-A04E</FirstVersionContractId>
   <OwnerId>MM-O-BDD15299</OwnerId>
   <Manufacturer>07</Manufacturer>
   <VehicleType>Car</VehicleType>
   <VehicleAgeFrom>0</VehicleAgeFrom>
   <VehicleAgeTo>0</VehicleAgeTo>
   <ClaimType>Unknown</ClaimType>
  </Contract>
  <Description>Alfa Romeo</Description>
  <PartnerId>MM-O-2A10BCF</PartnerId>
 </Partnership>
 <Partnership>
  <CountryOrganizationId>CZ</CountryOrganizationId>
  <PartnershipId>Contract_F5134A37-F39A-823A</PartnershipId>
  <OwnerId>MM-O-BDD15299</OwnerId>
  <PartnerIdList>
   <String>MM-O-2A10BCF</String>
  </PartnerIdList>
  <Contract>
   <CountryOrganizationId>CZ</CountryOrganizationId>
   <ContractId>Contract_F5134A37-F39A-823A</ContractId>
   <LaborRateList>
    <LaborRateDetail>
     <Role>Labor</Role>
     <Category>1</Category>
     <Rate Cur="CZK" Unit="h" MinValue="0" MaxValue="0">250.0</Rate>
    </LaborRateDetail>
    <LaborRateDetail>
     <Role>Paint</Role>
     <Category>2</Category>
     <Rate Cur="CZK" Unit="h" MinValue="0" MaxValue="0">350.0</Rate>
    </LaborRateDetail>
   </LaborRateList>
   <IdBlockCodeList>
    <IDBlockCode>
     <IDBlockCode>51</IDBlockCode>
     <Entry>100</Entry>
    </IDBlockCode>
   </IdBlockCodeList>
   <VehicleKind>Car</VehicleKind>
   <RepairKind>BodyRepair</RepairKind>
   <ManufacturerCode>10</ManufacturerCode>
   <Status>Active</Status>
   <CreatedBy>MM-P-69F997009BBFB4FC2C</CreatedBy>
   <CreationTimeStamp>2014-09-09T15:22:27.000</CreationTimeStamp>
   <UpdatedBy>MM-P-69F997009BBFB4FC2C</UpdatedBy>
   <UpdateTimeStamp>2014-10-15T13:11:36.000</UpdateTimeStamp>
   <FirstVersionContractId>Contract_F5134A37-F39A-823A</FirstVersionContractId>
   <OwnerId>MM-O-BDD15299</OwnerId>
   <Manufacturer>10</Manufacturer>
   <VehicleType>Car</VehicleType>
   <VehicleAgeFrom>0</VehicleAgeFrom>
   <VehicleAgeTo>0</VehicleAgeTo>
   <ClaimType>Unknown</ClaimType>
  </Contract>
  <Description>Citroën</Description>
  <PartnerId>MM-O-2A10BCF</PartnerId>
 </Partnership>
```

I google lots of tutorials but looks i am doing something wrong just at the begining. Can somebody give me any advise about it?

Thanks

Comment: The error messages are saying that your XML document is invalid. So fix your XML document.

Comment: you need to get the proper xml, its missing a parent node, and a closing on PartnershipList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an invalid XML document.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CreationDateTime>Wed Nov 05 12:30:38 CET 2014</CreationDateTime>
```

This is a complete XML document. It has an opening tag and a closing tag and that’s it. Anything else appended to the end of this document will render it invalid. An XML document can have only one root tag.

If you fix your XML document (perhaps by moving `<CreationDateTime>` inside `<PartnershipList>`, and making `<PartnershipList>` your root tag), PHP’s SimpleXML library will work.

Comment: thanks for answer, i understand it looks it's wrong document for PHP but how can i fix it? This is export i get.

Comment: If that's what you've got, then what you've got is not XML. It may be calling itself XML, but that's a lie. If there's no way to fix that export, you may need to build yourself a custom parser.

Comment: Thanks, now i understand. Will give you "RIGHT ANSWER" as soon as i will be possible

Answer (score 2):

As TRiG already said, the XML is incorrent. Instead of building a custom parser you can also edit the XML content before you parse it. The XML file should be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PartnerContainer>
<CreationDateTime>Wed Nov 05 12:30:38 CET 2014</CreationDateTime>
<PartnershipList xmlns="http://www.audatex.com/SAXIF">
 <Partnership>
  <CountryOrganizationId>CZ</CountryOrganizationId>
  <PartnershipId>Contract_58AB4635-D9C6-A04E</PartnershipId>
  <OwnerId>MM-O-BDD15299</OwnerId>
  <PartnerIdList>
   <String>MM-O-2A10BCF</String>
  </PartnerIdList>
  <Contract>
   <CountryOrganizationId>CZ</CountryOrganizationId>
   <ContractId>Contract_58AB4635-D9C6-A04E</ContractId>
   <LaborRateList>
    <LaborRateDetail>
     <Role>Labor</Role>
     <Category>1</Category>
     <Rate Cur="CZK" Unit="h" MinValue="0" MaxValue="0">250.0</Rate>
    </LaborRateDetail>
    <LaborRateDetail>
     <Role>Paint</Role>
     <Category>2</Category>
     <Rate Cur="CZK" Unit="h" MinValue="0" MaxValue="0">350.0</Rate>
    </LaborRateDetail>
   </LaborRateList>
   <IdBlockCodeList>
    <IDBlockCode>
     <IDBlockCode>51</IDBlockCode>
     <Entry>100</Entry>
    </IDBlockCode>
   </IdBlockCodeList>
   <VehicleKind>Car</VehicleKind>
   <RepairKind>BodyRepair</RepairKind>
   <ManufacturerCode>07</ManufacturerCode>
   <Status>Active</Status>
   <CreatedBy>MM-P-69F997009BBFB4FC2C</CreatedBy>
   <CreationTimeStamp>2014-09-09T15:17:46.000</CreationTimeStamp>
   <UpdatedBy>MM-P-69F997009BBFB4FC2C</UpdatedBy>
   <UpdateTimeStamp>2014-10-15T10:49:18.000</UpdateTimeStamp>
   <FirstVersionContractId>Contract_58AB4635-D9C6-A04E</FirstVersionContractId>
   <OwnerId>MM-O-BDD15299</OwnerId>
   <Manufacturer>07</Manufacturer>
   <VehicleType>Car</VehicleType>
   <VehicleAgeFrom>0</VehicleAgeFrom>
   <VehicleAgeTo>0</VehicleAgeTo>
   <ClaimType>Unknown</ClaimType>
  </Contract>
  <Description>Alfa Romeo</Description>
  <PartnerId>MM-O-2A10BCF</PartnerId>
 </Partnership>
 <Partnership>
  <CountryOrganizationId>CZ</CountryOrganizationId>
  <PartnershipId>Contract_F5134A37-F39A-823A</PartnershipId>
  <OwnerId>MM-O-BDD15299</OwnerId>
  <PartnerIdList>
   <String>MM-O-2A10BCF</String>
  </PartnerIdList>
  <Contract>
   <CountryOrganizationId>CZ</CountryOrganizationId>
   <ContractId>Contract_F5134A37-F39A-823A</ContractId>
   <LaborRateList>
    <LaborRateDetail>
     <Role>Labor</Role>
     <Category>1</Category>
     <Rate Cur="CZK" Unit="h" MinValue="0" MaxValue="0">250.0</Rate>
    </LaborRateDetail>
    <LaborRateDetail>
     <Role>Paint</Role>
     <Category>2</Category>
     <Rate Cur="CZK" Unit="h" MinValue="0" MaxValue="0">350.0</Rate>
    </LaborRateDetail>
   </LaborRateList>
   <IdBlockCodeList>
    <IDBlockCode>
     <IDBlockCode>51</IDBlockCode>
     <Entry>100</Entry>
    </IDBlockCode>
   </IdBlockCodeList>
   <VehicleKind>Car</VehicleKind>
   <RepairKind>BodyRepair</RepairKind>
   <ManufacturerCode>10</ManufacturerCode>
   <Status>Active</Status>
   <CreatedBy>MM-P-69F997009BBFB4FC2C</CreatedBy>
   <CreationTimeStamp>2014-09-09T15:22:27.000</CreationTimeStamp>
   <UpdatedBy>MM-P-69F997009BBFB4FC2C</UpdatedBy>
   <UpdateTimeStamp>2014-10-15T13:11:36.000</UpdateTimeStamp>
   <FirstVersionContractId>Contract_F5134A37-F39A-823A</FirstVersionContractId>
   <OwnerId>MM-O-BDD15299</OwnerId>
   <Manufacturer>10</Manufacturer>
   <VehicleType>Car</VehicleType>
   <VehicleAgeFrom>0</VehicleAgeFrom>
   <VehicleAgeTo>0</VehicleAgeTo>
   <ClaimType>Unknown</ClaimType>
  </Contract>
  <Description>Citroën</Description>
  <PartnerId>MM-O-2A10BCF</PartnerId>
 </Partnership>
 </PartnershipList>
</PartnerContainer>
```

In PHP, call a `file_get_contents` to get the XML content so you can edit the XML content with functions like `str_replace`. After that you can parse the XML string with `simplexml_load_string`. I think you are already done if you do the things below but i'm not sure, didn't test:

```
$xnl_file = "xml.xml";
$xml = file_get_contents($xnl_file);
$xml = str_replace('<CreationDateTime>','<PartnerContainer><CreationDateTime>',$xml);
$xml .= '</PartnershipList></PartnerContainer>';
```