# load xml file to php dynamic

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml

How can I load xml file to php dynamic

```html
$viq="VPQ/" echo $Recordset1['vname'] ;
    $xml=simplexml_load_file($viq) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
```

noraml code is $xml=simplexml_load_file(12345.xml) or .......

```html
$colname_Recordset1 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $colname_Recordset1 = $_GET['id'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_noonopic, $noonopic);
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM xmlsheet WHERE id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordset1, "int"));
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $noonopic) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

$viq="VPQ/" echo $Recordset1['vname'] ;
$xml=simplexml_load_file($viq) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML load file with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756920/xml-load-file-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

```html
$viq='VPQ/'.$row_Recordset1; ;
    $xml=simplexml_load_file($viq) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
```